# Return a result set in numeric pattern / sequence

Tags: mysql, design-patterns, sequence, resultset

I have a problem in hand and that is to fetch a result set in a numeric pattern / sequence based on a single column's value.

Say I have the following table:

```
+-------+  
| val   |  
+-------+
| 1     |
| 1     |
| 1     |
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 2     |
| 2     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
| 3     |
| 3     |
| 3     |
+-------+
```

How can I make it this way instead:

```
+-------+  
| val   |  
+-------+
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
+-------+
```

#### Case mentioned by aularon:

What if one of the values do not have enough to fill the gaps, what is the expected behaviour? Say we replace two of the 3's to be 8's

```
+-------+  
| val   |  
+-------+
| 1     |
| 1     |
| 1     |
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 2     |
| 2     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
| 3     |
| 8     |
| 8     |
+-------+
```

I'd still expect it to go in numeric sequence of smallest first, then largest, then smallest, then largest.

```
+-------+  
| val   |  
+-------+
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
| 8     |
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
| 8     |
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 1     |
| 2     |
+-------+
```

Comment: What's the expected behavior if there wasn't enough 3's? like for example if we switched two of the sample 3's with 8's?

Comment: Hi aularon, take a look at the updated question =)

Comment: Is there any derivable logic in the result you are expecting?  I mean, will your result always take ascending order of numbers in pairs of 3 rows only?

Comment: Can you give a psweudo code / rough algorithm on exactly what are the rules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what we call a major `rownum` hack.  Let's say your table is named t and your value column is named val.  This will give the result you're looking for.

```
SELECT val    /* step 6 */
FROM
(SELECT A.val, 
   CASE 
   WHEN A.val <> IFNULL(B.val,-1) THEN @q:=0   /* step 4 */
   ELSE @q:=@q+1                               /* step 4 */ 
    END AS seq                                 /* step 4 */
   FROM
    (SELECT @q:=0)r,
    (SELECT                          /* step 1 */
            @a:=@a+1 AS n,           /* step 1 */
            val                      /* step 1 */
      FROM  (SELECT @a:= 0)r, T      /* step 1 */
     ORDER BY val) A                 /* step 1 */
   LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT                        /* step 2, like step 1 */
            @b:=@b+1 AS n, 
            val
       FROM  (SELECT @b:= 0)r, T
     ORDER BY val) B
    ON B.n = A.n-1    /* step 3 */
 ORDER BY seq,val) s  /* step 5 */
```

A word or two of explanation:

1. We need to turn your val table into
   a val,n table (where n is the row
   number)
2. Then we need two of those, with
   independent row numbers @a and @b
3. Then we need to join them together
   with a row = row-1 offset to compare
   adjacent val columns.
4. Then we need to apply a sequence
   number to each val column, that
   resets.  That is, we need to give
   sequence numbers 1,2,3 to the 1s, then the 2s,
   etc.
5. Then we need to sort by seq, then
   val.
6. Then we need to conceal the seqs.

Lo and behold....

Hack hack!

Comment: That's awesome! Great enough for me to start working on how to integrate. Thanks! How about integrating this into a result set instead of the entire table?

Comment: If I understand your result-set question, I think what you do is get rid of step 6, add some columns to the subquery in step 1, and mention those column names right above step 4 in my query.

Comment: Oh, and whatever you do with the step 1 subquery, make sure it and the step 2 subquery have the same rows in the same order as each other, or you'll get strange rubble.